# How to import a SQL Server table in to Access and have the fields retain their datatypes?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have a table in a SQL Server database with a `varchar(20)` primary key and several fields with assorted datatypes - `int`, `text`, `datetime`, `integer`, `nvarchar(max)`, etc.

I can import this table into Access using External Data->ODBC Database successfully but I noticed all fields have their datatype set to MEMO except for the PK, which becomes `TEXT`.

How can I import the table TO Access and have the fields retain their datatypes?

Or alternately, how can I export the table FROM SqlServer and have the fields retain their datatypes?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot retain the SQL Server data types in Access, they do not use the same types.

Have a look at the *equivalent* data type in Access for the SQL Server types:

[How Access sees SQL Server data types](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/import-or-link-access-to-sql-server-data-HA010341762.aspx#BM5)

I realise the article I'm linking to is talking about moving data in the opposite direction to your situation but it was the first link I found when searching Google.